# como puedo hacer para llevar las dos variables al servicio Ionic 4 + angular

Tags: ionic4, angular8

¿Como puedo hacer para llevar los objetos **`contraseñas = [];`**
        **`correos = [];`** a mi servicio?

esto es posible o tengo que hacerlo de otra manera ?

**tab1page.ts:**

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
    import { LogsService } from '../services/logs.service';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-tab1',
      templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
    })
    export class Tab1Page {
     swiperOpts = {
       allowSlidePrev: false,
       allowSlideNext: false
     };
     contrasenas = [];
    correos = [];
      constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, public LogsService: LogsService) {}
    conrasena() {
      this.LogsService.login();
    }
    }
```

**servicio:**

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
    import { Tab1PageModule } from '../tab1/tab1.module';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class LogsService {



      constructor(private navCtrl: NavController) { }
      login( Tab1PageModule ) {

        let newContra;
        let newCR;

        newContra = this.contrasenas;
        newCR = this.correos;


        if(newCR = this.correos){
        if(newContra = this.contrasenas){
        console.log(newCR);
        console.log(newContra);
        console.log('Entraste con exito');
        } else {
          console.log('contraseña incorrecta');
        }
      } else {
        console.log('correo invalido');
      }
        console.log( newContra);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Agrega  más información, no logro entender el problema

Comment: Bienvenido a **StackOverflow** , te recomiendo que realices el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y asi obtengas tu primera medalla, ademas mira [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para asi poder ayudarte mejor.